# AS3 API: Deleting App Invites

Tags: facebook-graph-api, invite

I'm using the ActionScript-Facebook API for my project. Facebook now leaves it up to us to delete app invites once they are used.

In their documentation, they have a JavaScript snippet to do what I need to do:

```
FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {console.log(response);});
```

Cool. The AS3 API call is like such:

```
Facebook.api(referID, callback, "POST");
```

For the life of me, I'm not sure how to work this. I've tried:

```
Facebook.api(referID, function(){trace("callback");}, "delete");

Facebook.api(referID, function(){trace("callback");});

Facebook.api(referID, {access_token:accessTokenString}, "delete");
```

Here's the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting

Comment: afaik the referID is not only the request ID but the concat of request_id and (importend) current user id, so if you dont auth the invited user you no longer can delete the request.... very stupid if you ask me.

Comment: without user it only seems to work with the JS call see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting
`DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<request_id>_<user_id>]?
      access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for removal of application requests:

```
var full_request_id : String = request_id + "_" + user_id;
var method : String =  "/" + full_request_id;
Facebook.deleteObject(method, callback);
```

*@see AbstractFacebook.as* 
The actionscript-api will then add the property 'method' with value 'delete' to the parameters of your call:

```
protected function deleteObject(method:String, callback:Function = null):void {
        var params:Object = {method:'delete'};
        api(method, callback, params, URLRequestMethod.POST);
    }

if (params.access_token == null) { params.access_token = accessToken; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Antoine.

I found the deleteObject() call a few hours (of hair-pulling) after I posted this and it worked for me.