# How to delete application requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-actionscript-api

Question: 
**How to delete an application request using the facebook-actionscript-api?**

I am trying to delete application requests making this call in Actionscript:

```
Facebook.api(full_request_id, callback, "delete", "POST");
```

The Actionscript API then throws the following error:

> Exception fault: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property access_token
>   not found on String and there is no default value.    at
>   com.facebook.graph.core::AbstractFacebook/api()[C:\Users\facebookGraphApi\api\com\facebook\graph\core\AbstractFacebook.as:134

Which is logical as the script at that point tries to access the value of params which is now the String "delete":

```
if (params.access_token == null) { params.access_token = accessToken; }
```

Related questions: [AS3 API: Deleting App Invites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016668/as3-api-deleting-app-invites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for removal of application requests:

```
var full_request_id : String = request_id + "_" + user_id;
var method : String =  "/" + full_request_id;
Facebook.deleteObject(method, callback);
```

*@see AbstractFacebook.as* 
The actionscript-api will then add the property 'method' with value 'delete' to the parameters of your call:

```
protected function deleteObject(method:String, callback:Function = null):void {
        var params:Object = {method:'delete'};
        api(method, callback, params, URLRequestMethod.POST);
    }

if (params.access_token == null) { params.access_token = accessToken; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'params' null or not an object? that would easily explain why 'access_token' isn't coming back when you try to access params.access_token

Comment: 'params' is an object of type String, i.e. "delete" in the call:
`Facebook.api(full_request_id, callback, "delete", "POST");`

From the documentation, this is how to make the Javascript call:
`FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });`

How would I make the same call in Actionscript?

Comment: Well if it's a string, that's why you can't call params.access_token -   unfortunately i'm not sure how to supply an access token in the AS SDK

Comment: Found the answer:

    var full_request_id : String = request_id + "_" + user_id;
    var method : String =  "/" + full_request_id;
    Facebook.deleteObject(method, callback);

*@see AbstractFacebook.as* 
The actionscript-api will then add the property 'method' with value 'delete' to the parameters of your call:

    protected function deleteObject(method:String, callback:Function = null):void {
            var params:Object = {method:'delete'};
            api(method, callback, params, URLRequestMethod.POST);
        }